# Export IOS build (IPA) from "Mono for Android" Application

Tags: android, ios, mono, cross-platform

I am trying to build a crossplatform test application. I have downloaded all tools required for "Mono For Android" & created a test project in MonoDevelop IDE. Its runs on Android Emulator. Now since this is a crossplatform, i should have option of exporting the code to IPhone or deliver/export .ipa